# How to write Dynamic SqL Query for like Search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have some problem writing SQL Dynamic Query for like Search.
I wanna get for some help for my problem.Please show me road map to my project.
I got result for ACode BCode CCode  but DCode not get result. 
ACode Bcode CCode can get correct Results. 
DCode can't get result. I want  assign DCode with LIKE SEARCH <<'% DCode %'>>.
PLease HELP. 
Thank you who interests my Ques :)

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[BDSPag] 
( 
 @Acode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @BCode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @CCode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @DCode nvarchar(200)=null
)
AS         
BEGIN


Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
        Declare @SqlParams nvarchar(max)
        Set @SQL = 'Select  ACode, BCode, CCode, DCode  FROM  tblCollection where 1=1'
        if(@Acode is not null) -- gp Code
        set @SQL= @SQL+' and CategoriesCode= @CC'
            if(@BCode is not null)--B Code
        set @SQL= @SQL+' and GItem= @GI'
            if(@CCode is not null) --C Code
        set @SQL= @SQL+' and CtdCode= @CtdC'


         declare @Paran nvarchar(150)
          set @Paran=' and DCode LIKE '''+ '%' + '@GN' + '%' + '''' 
        set @SQL= @SQL+  @Paran
     Execute sp_executesql @SQL,
         N'@CC nvarchar(100), @GI nvarchar(100), @CtdC nvarchar(100), @RecU nvarchar(100),@GIU nvarchar(100), @GN nvarchar(100) ',
         @CC=@ACode, @GI=@BCode, @CtdC=@CCode ,@GN=@DCode
    End
```

Comment: Throw a `SELECT @SQL` in there and see what you've got for a query after the dynamic generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to treat the Like parameters any different that the other parameters. Just add the '%' wildcards inside the parameter value.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[BDSPag] 
( 
 @Acode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @BCode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @CCode nvarchar(100)=null,    
 @DCode nvarchar(200)=null
)
AS         
BEGIN

  set @DCode = '%' + @DCode + '%'

  Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
  Declare @SqlParams nvarchar(max)

  set @SqlParams = N'@CC nvarchar(100), @GI nvarchar(100), @CtdC nvarchar(100), @RecU nvarchar(100),@GIU nvarchar(100), @GN nvarchar(100) '

  Set @SQL = 'Select  ACode, BCode, CCode, DCode  FROM  tblCollection where 1=1'

  if(@Acode is not null) -- gp Code
    set @SQL= @SQL+' and CategoriesCode= @CC'
  if(@BCode is not null)--B Code
    set @SQL= @SQL+' and GItem= @GI'
  if(@CCode is not null) --C Code
    set @SQL= @SQL+' and CtdCode= @CtdC'
  if(@Dcode is not null) --D Code 
    set @SQL= @SQL+' and DCode like @GN'

  print @SQL -- Show the SQL statement to execute

  Execute sp_executesql @SQL,
                        @SqlParams,
                        @CC=@ACode, @GI=@BCode, @CtdC=@CCode, @GN=@DCode
End
```

Comment: THANKS YOU @Marc Guillot. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @NweNi you are welcome. By the way, your code didn't work because the final #SQL was : DCode LIKE '%#GN%', but it should have been DCode LIKE '%' + #GN + '%' It would be that or putting the wildcards inside the parameter value as I have proposed to you (those # should be @ but Stackoverflow doesn't allow them, because they are used to referiantate the users you are answering to)

Comment: I got searched results from that query and I want to create those results into custom paging. Is It possibly?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can add the OFFSET and FETCH NEXT clauses to get the result in packets. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/

Comment: @NweNi Your query needs to have an ORDER BY, to return the result in that order. The first packet of 50 rows would be : .... OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY. The second packet of 50 rows : .... OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY. The third packet of 50 rows : .... OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY.